# core : is not a core dump: File format not recognized

Tags: gdb, coredump

The GDB displayed that my core file is not a core dump. I am using the Linux version 4.1 ARM 32bit. I have set my core file in /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern. When I observe the crash, the crash dump was written in to the core file. I have used "hexdump" to make sure that the ELF header was proper and it seems the header written properly and executed the command "file" and it displayed as core file but it is not saying the exe name.

**Output :**

file ../../../core 
../../../core: ELF 32-bit LSB  core file ARM, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style

When I use the core file in GDB. The GDB displayed that it is not a core dump file and the file format is not recognized.

I am wondering the file command is saying that the file is core but the GDB is not recognizing that file. Not sure what is the issue here.

**Note :** Cross compiled GDB version - GNU gdb (GDB) 7.10.1 is used.

Comment: What does `gdb --version` say? Is your GDB configured for 32-bit ARM?

Comment: The gdb that we received as part of crosstools-arm-gcc-5.3. and the version is 7.10.1.   "This GDB was configured as "---host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --target=arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi"